# How to move stepper from one step to second step using angular and angular material

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-material-stepper, mat-stepper

I have 2 - 4 step form. I had separate out the form like below structure.
 First there is `auth` folder under then  there `register` folder. Under this `register` - `register.ts` and `register.html`. Under `register.html` I had implemented `mat stepper` like below :

```
 <mat-horizontal-stepper [linear]="isLinear" #stepper>

                    <mat-step [stepControl]="firstFormGroup">
                      <form [formGroup]="firstFormGroup">
                        <ng-template matStepLabel> step 1 </ng-template>
                        <mat-card class="example-card">
                                <mat-card-header>
                                    <div mat-card-avatar class="example-header-image"></div>
                                    <mat-card-title>step 1</mat-card-title>
                                </mat-card-header>
                                <mat-card-content>
                                        <kt-stepone></kt-stepone>
                                </mat-card-content>

                        </mat-card>

                        <div>

                        </div>
                      </form>
                    </mat-step>

                    <mat-step [stepControl]="secondFormGroup">
                      <form [formGroup]="secondFormGroup">
                        <ng-template matStepLabel> step 2 </ng-template>
                            <mat-card class="example-card">
                                <mat-card-header>
                                    <div mat-card-avatar class="example-header-image"></div>
                                    <mat-card-title>step 2</mat-card-title>
                                </mat-card-header>
                                <mat-card-content>
                                        <kt-steptwo></kt-steptwo>
                                </mat-card-content>
                            </mat-card>

                      </form>
                    </mat-step>
```

under my `register.ts` :

```
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  isLinear = true;
}
```

Now this 
`<kt-stepone>` is my step 1 form which is separate module and there I implemented the Next button.

Now when I implemented `isLinear = true;` then even after filling the whole form its not going on next step. If I didnt fill the form then its working as per expection highligting the fileds with red

For ref, here is `<kt-stepone>`code :

```
<form class="kt-form" [formGroup]="steponeForm" autocomplete="off" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
            <div class="kt-portlet__body" >
                //MY FORM
            </div>
                 // submit button
            <button mat-button matStepperNext color="primary" type="submit">Next</button>

</form>
```

Since I am using angular for first time, please tell me where I am making mistake in this approach.

Updated KT-STEPONE.ts:

```
import { MatStepper } from '@angular/material/stepper';
completed=false;
@ViewChild('stepper') stepper: MatStepper;
onSubmit(){

    this.stepper.selected.completed = true;
    this.stepper.next();
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After RnD over this. I had finally got the working solution of this. Please follow this [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-umvpjs?file=app%2Fstep-one.component.ts). The way to do this is : We need to link up the every step component in register component. [Here](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/8021) is the guide for this.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your stepper and kt-stepone are not comunicating. try implement a service or a @inpit @output to set step valid. or if your logic is separated you can remove the  [stepControl]
and 
set completed="false"
and in your component

```
@ViewChild('stepper') stepper: MatStepper;
onButton() {
  this.stepper.selected.completed = true;
  this.stepper.next();
}
```

Comment: Where should I include `@ViewChild('stepper') stepper: MatStepper;` . Should I include this before constructor in class OR before class itself ? Also, MatStepper means its MatStepperModule ? @Lean Pilar

Comment: Please find the updated kt-stepone.ts as per your instructions. but it going in next step even if fields are empty @Lean Pilar

Comment: inside the class before constructor in class where you use the mat-horizontal-stepper

Comment: mat-horizontal-stepper is in my main register.html. From mat-horizontal-stepper,  I removed the `[stepControl]`. where should I add `completed="false"`, I mean which ts file: register or kt-stepone @Lean Pilar

Comment: replace [stepControl]=... with completed="false". but if you don't have button on the stepper but onli iinside try to emit and event from the kt-stepone to the stepper to listen for the event and trigger the onButton function

Comment: Ok will try to do this. It will be helpful if you can you help me out with an example.

Answer (score 0):

```
<mat-step [stepControl]="firstFormGroup">
    <form [formGroup]="firstFormGroup">
        <ng-template matStepLabel> step 1 </ng-template>
        <mat-card class="example-card">
            <mat-card-header>
                <div mat-card-avatar class="example-header-image"></div>
                <mat-card-title>step 1</mat-card-title>
            </mat-card-header>
            <mat-card-content>
                <kt-stepone></kt-stepone>
            </mat-card-content>

        </mat-card>

        <div>

        </div>
    </form>
</mat-step>
<mat-step [stepControl]="secondFormGroup">
    <form [formGroup]="secondFormGroup">
        <ng-template matStepLabel> step 2 </ng-template>
        <mat-card class="example-card">
            <mat-card-header>
                <div mat-card-avatar class="example-header-image"></div>
                <mat-card-title>step 2</mat-card-title>
            </mat-card-header>
            <mat-card-content>
                <kt-steptwo></kt-steptwo>
            </mat-card-content>
        </mat-card>

    </form>
</mat-step>
```